# 質問の投稿時に表示されるヒントがモバイル環境で正常に動作しない

Tags: バグ, モバイル

#### 1点目 (不具合報告)

スマホから「質問する」ページにアクセスした際、タイトルの上にヒントのボックスが表示されますが、
「ステップ1: 質問を下書きする」をタップ後に表示されるサブ項目が反応しません。

「1. 問題を要約する」「これまでに試したことを説明」「3. コードを表示」をそれぞれタップしても、内容が表示されません。

該当部分はレスポンシブデザインになっており、PCからのアクセス時は投稿フォームの右側に表示されますが、
スマホでもブラウザの「PC表示」を使用すれば正常に動作します。

また、PCからはブラウザの開発者ツールでモバイル表示をエミュレートすると不具合が再現します。

##### 他の姉妹サイトでの状況

- 英語版の質問ページは独自に先行して改良が進んでおり、ウィザード形式での表示になっています。
- MSE や Server Fault 等でもやはり日本語版とは表示が違い、メニューは入れ子になっておらず1つずつ表示されます。
  (日本語版での表示のみ古いまま置いて行かれてる？)

#### 2点目 (改善要望)

正常に動作しているサイトも含めて、該当のヒントは質問ページにアクセスした際「閉じた」状態で表示されますが、
こういった注意書きのようなメニューは (本当に読んで欲しい人に限って) 読まれないのが常です。
できればデフォルトで開いた状態でヒントを表示されるようにして欲しいです。

この手の要望は英語版だと「毎回表示されるのは煩わしい」と反発されそうですが、それこそ信用度に応じて表示を切り替えるなどいくらでもやり方はあるはずです。

---

#### 現状の表示例

**ページを開いた直後:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**質問を下書きするをタップしてメニューを展開した状態:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**(参考) Server Fault での表示例:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]