# Stack Exchange社からの伝達にはモデレーター専用タグの使用を徹底して欲しい

Tags: 討議, 対応予定, タグ

このメタサイトにおいては、報告されている問題や、提案、議論などに関し、Stack Exchange社から決定や現在の状態を知らせていただくことがあります。その際、モデレーター専用タグを使用していただくと、ユーザーにも状況が解り易くなり、検索も可能になり、大変助かります。現在も多くの投稿にモデレーター専用タグが付けられていますが、より徹底して付与していただければ有効性が高まるので、ぜひお願いしたいと思います。

ここで「モデレーター専用タグ」と言っているのは、[完了](/questions/tagged/%e5%ae%8c%e4%ba%86) [対応予定](/questions/tagged/%e5%af%be%e5%bf%9c%e4%ba%88%e5%ae%9a) [仕様](/questions/tagged/%e4%bb%95%e6%a7%98) [延期](/questions/tagged/%e5%bb%b6%e6%9c%9f) [却下](/questions/tagged/%e5%8d%b4%e4%b8%8b) [再現済](/questions/tagged/%e5%86%8d%e7%8f%be%e6%b8%88) [再現性なし](/questions/tagged/%e5%86%8d%e7%8f%be%e6%80%a7%e3%81%aa%e3%81%97) [調査中](/questions/tagged/%e8%aa%bf%e6%9f%bb%e4%b8%ad) などです。

「徹底」というのは、

- コメントや回答の投稿で応答いただく場合も、公式タグの付与や変更を行なって欲しい
- 投稿を書く労力が割けない場合は、公式タグだけでも付与して欲しい

といった意味です。

---

例:

- [質問の投稿時に表示されるヒントがモバイル環境で正常に動作しない](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3850/3054) → 状況不明
- [コミュニティバナーの文がダークモードだと読めない](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3759/3054) → 「延期」が削除されたので意図としては「完了」と思われます
- [当サイトのタイトル](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/13/3054) → [別箇所](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3848/3054) にて応答いただいており、当時の議論は「完了」と思われます
- [ブランド展開戦略: 「日本語版」と言わない](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1433/3054) → 上と同じく、当時の提案は「却下」と思われます
- [コメント入力中でのEnterの動作](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2496/3054) → 回答などから「完了」と思われます
- [このサイトの翻訳ファイルの著作権保持者は誰ですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3794/3054) → 状況不明

特に2014年のサイト名の議論には巨大なディスコミュニケーションが生じており、決定に際し文章による応答が面倒であっても、モデレーター専用タグの付与さえ行なわれていれば、ユーザー側から問題に気付くことができたと思われます。

Comment: 参考: 関連しそうな英語版メタの投稿 - [Did thousands of "feature-request" posts get forgotten, without anyone adding the "status-declined" (or other statuses) tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415778/2322778)